# Out of memory issue with JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am facing **out of memory** issue while generating multiple small PDF reports (say 50000 reports , 2-3 page each, file size of 50 to 60 KB). The out of memory error I get after 3000 report generated.

After execution of below line, I see the memory is not getting cleaned up.

```
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(compiledPath,
        file.getPath(), null, dataSource);
```

I have tried the below alternate code using JRSwapFileVirtualizer, but it did not help the issue.

```
dataSource = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(myBean);
swapFile =  new JRSwapFile(outputFileLocation, 1024, 1024);
virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(3,swapFile, true);

parameterMap = new HashMap();
parameterMap.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);


JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(compiledPath,
        file.getPath(), parameterMap, dataSource);

dataSource = null;
virtualizer.cleanup();

jasperPrint = (JasperPrint) JRLoader.loadObject(file);

compiledPath = null;
file = null;


pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,
    jasperPrint);
pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
    finalOutputfile.toString());

pdfExporter.exportReport();
```

Any suggestion on how to clean up memory after each report is generated will be helpful.

Comment: [JRSwapFile](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRSwapFile.html) needs a dispose for instance, but that does not concern the first version. Do you close all things closeable?

Comment: @JoopEggen: Nullified each object in finally. Did not find any closeable object. virtualizer.cleanup() takes care of the dispose. My scenario is generation of lots of small files, hence wondering if Virtualizer will be useful. With or without virtualizer, i do not see much memory getting cleaned after last line is executed.

Comment: @ad-inf Can I ask what template file do you use for your application? .jrxml and .jasper could have huge difference on performance..

Comment: @Dreamer: using .jasper

Comment: @ad-inf then I think the best way to tell is turn on logging to more verbose level, normally there will be quite a big chunk of going on before your application throws the "out of memory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about pojo or traditional JSP web application, but with my spring application, it used to have the same out of memory issue. I pull out of the trace logging and find out a lot info on rendering the template. It make me remember that `jrxml` is a pre-compile template instead of `.jasper`. So i replace all my templates then out of memory issue never happen again. Please consider this as addition to @Joop Eggen's advice.

Comment: I take this as answer since this is generally solution for Jasper report memory issue. Meanwhile my issue was on the code which was invoking the report generation in a loop, which I could rectify.